# nonzero sequence of numbers with arbitrarily small sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to have sequence of numbers $\{f(a)\}$ with the following properties:
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(a)<a$, for all a>0
also, $f_i(a)>0$ 

 can someone give a sequence with these properties.

Comment: How about $\{\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{4}, \frac{a}{8}, \dots \}$ ?

Comment: Try $f_i(a)=3^{-i}a$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(a)=a/2<a$ for all $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_i(a):=\frac{f_i(a)}a>0$. It suffices to have $$\sum_i g_i(a)<1$$ and this is can be achieved by any convergent positive series (with a scaling factor), in particular with a definition independent of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum _{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {a}{2^n} = \frac {a}{2} <a $$